# Python: Group Unique ids and Merge Values into an Array

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-indexing

I have a `pandas` DF that looks like this

DF:

```
       name ;time_cost
        x   ;28800000, 250 
        x   ;39600000, 300 
        x   ;61200000, 250 
        x   ;72000000, 0 
        y   ;86400000, 0 
        y   ;115200000, 250 
        y   ;126000000, 300 
        y   ;147600000, 250
        y   ;158400000, 0

df.head().to_dict()
{'name': {0: 'x',
          1: 'x',
          2: 'x',
          3: 'x'},
 'time_cost': {0: '28800000, 250',
                1: '39600000, 300',
                2: '61200000, 250',
                0: '72000000, 0'}}
```

I'm trying to put all the values from time_cost into an array like so:

```
[[[28800000, 250],
[39600000, 300],
[61200000, 250],
[72000000, 0 ],
[86400000, 0 ]],
[[115200000, 250],
[126000000, 300],
[147600000, 250],
[158400000, 0]]]
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
    import pandas as pd

        df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
        def f(df):
            return pd.Series(dict(timecost_range = "%s" % '| '.join(df['time_cost'])))

        result = df.groupby('name').apply(f)
        result
                timecost_range
        name    
        x       28800000, 250| 39600000, 300| 61200000, 250| 72000000, 0
        y       86400000, 0| 115200000, 250| 126000000, 300| 147600000, 250|...
```

This works somewhat, but isn't exactly what I am looking for. Any ideas or suggestions would be useful.

Comment: What is the CSV separator used here?

Comment: Can you add `df.head().to_dict()` to the question. I think it's ambiguous as to how `'time_cost'` is stored in your `DataFrame`

Comment: Also, are there only these two (three) columns in `df` or can there be more?

Comment: Hi @ALollz I've edited my question. @coldspeed  the CSV separator is `sep=';'`, and yes there are only two (three) columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example, data is:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'x',
          1: 'x',
          2: 'x',
          3: 'y'},
 'time_cost': {0: '28800000, 250',
                1: '39600000, 300',
                2: '61200000, 250',
                3: '72000000, 0'}})
```

**Step 1.** You can use something like this to get result:

```
def split_function(n):
    return n.split(',')

df['time_cost'] = df.time_cost.apply(split_function)
```

Output:

```
name         time_cost
0    x  [28800000,  250]
1    x  [39600000,  300]
2    x  [61200000,  250]
3    y    [72000000,  0]
```

**Step 2.** If you want two different columns in your DataFrame you can use:

```
df.time_cost.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
          0     1
0  28800000   250
1  39600000   300
2  61200000   250
3  72000000     0
```

**Step 3.** And then join them:

```
df = df.join(df.time_cost.apply(pd.Series))
```

Output:

```
name         time_cost         0     1
0    x  [28800000,  250]  28800000   250
1    x  [39600000,  300]  39600000   300
2    x  [61200000,  250]  61200000   250
3    y    [72000000,  0]  72000000     0
```

And then you can use `drop` to drop "time_cost" column and `rename` to rename new columns if you like.

Is it what you want? I hope it will be helpful.

**UPD:**

**Step 4.** If you want grouped by name, you can use this:

```
df[0] = df[0].astype(int)
df[1] = df[1].astype(int)

def concat_function_0(df):
    return np.array(df[0])
def concat_function_1(df):
    return np.array(df[1])

df = pd.DataFrame([df.groupby('name').apply(concat_function_1), df.groupby('name').apply(concat_function_0)]).T
```

It isn't pythonic, but it works = )

Output:

```
name               0                               1                                                 
x     [250, 300, 250]  [28800000, 39600000, 61200000]
y                 [0]                      [72000000]
```

**UPD:**

**Step 5.** For your result, after first step use this:

```
def df_to_array(df):
    return list(df.time_cost)

result = df.groupby('name').apply(df_to_array).values
```

Output:

```
[[['28800000', ' 250'], ['39600000', ' 300'], ['61200000', ' 250']]
 [['72000000', ' 0']]]
```

Comment: Hi @Anna Iliukovich-Strakovskaia, thank you for your response. This is close, but I need to `groupby` `name` and then some how merge the `time_cost` values together in an array like so: `[[[28800000, 250],
[39600000, 300],
[61200000, 250],
[72000000, 0 ],
[86400000, 0 ]],
[[115200000, 250],
[126000000, 300],
[147600000, 250],
[158400000, 0]]]`

Comment: Hi! @mm_nieder see the last update. I didn't understand what you want first time = ). Does last update help?

Comment: @mm_nieder So you don't need step 2-4, but I think it can be helpful for other peoples.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your brilliant answer :) Very helpful!